# Adobe PDF Embed API - How to generate the file ID for metaData

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am using Adobe PDF Embedded API to view, edit & save the PDF and it is working fine.

To get the annotations I have found the below code:

```
 document.addEventListener("adobe_dc_view_sdk.ready", function()

 {

  var adobeDCView = new AdobeDC.View({clientId: "<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>", divId: "adobe-dc-view"});

  var previewFilePromise = adobeDCView.previewFile({

   content:   {location: {url: "https://documentcloud.adobe.com/view-sdk-demo/PDFs/Bodea Brochure.pdf"}},
   //id is 
   metaData:  {
          fileName: "Bodea Brochure.pdf", 
           /* file ID */
          id: "77c6fa5d-6d74-4104-8349-657c8411a834"}

  },

  {

   enableAnnotationAPIs: true,

  });


  previewFilePromise.then(adobeViewer => {

   adobeViewer.getAnnotationManager().then(annotationManager => {

    // All annotation APIs can be invoked here

   });

  });

 });
```

Found this note from the documentation:

```
To enabled the annotation APIs, you must pass a PDF ID in the metadata field when invoking the previewFile API. This ID uniquely identifies the PDF so that annotations can be added.
```

Can anyone tell me how to get the **PDF ID** to add inside a **metaData** Object.

Comment: did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply provide an arbitrary string as the `id`. It should be document-specific, such as a database ID that you might have generated inside your application. It could also be the document's name, if you can safely assume that it is unique.

The idea seems to be to distinguish between different, parallel annotation processes. But it doesn't become completely clear from the [documentation](https://developer.adobe.com/document-services/docs/overview/pdf-embed-api/howtos_comments/#annotations-interface), what this `id` is actually used for, like if it is just used locally in the browser or not.